# basic template for ngx-admin with basic beahviour

Tags: angular, ngx-admin

Is there a starter app which avoids starting with the full template?
It should be useful to have a skeleton start with minimum dependencies and then add components\modules from it.

Comment: I've used this in the past and can say no, there isn't. They only have the full ngx-admin which you can download, which from personal experience, I would definitely not recommend doing. Best thing for you to do would be to start an empty Angular project and add to it yourself.

Comment: I've asked the question becaouse I've been through the full template download and found it overwhelming and confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have a branch for that, not sure how updated it's kept.

> https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/tree/starter-kit

It gives you a basic layout

- Header
- Footer
- Sidebar
- Main dashboard page
- Auth pages (Login, register, request pass, reset pass)
- No filler pages

[image: ngx-admin-start-kit screenshot]

Comment: perfect it's the skeleton I was looking at!